# Hadoop more machines or more powerful machines

Tags: hadoop, virtualization

If I'm using virtualization for my cluster is it better to have more machines or smaller number of powerful machines (cpu,memory)?

The usecase I'm using it for is cpu intensive.

Comment: Cloud machines are cheap enough that you should be able to micro benchmark your load with different configurations with (probably) better results than anyone taking a guess without knowing the details.